# Salesforce Ajax call throwing exception

Tags: ajax

I have the following ajax call that I am sending to an outside domain. but it straights goes to error function is there something that I am missing . I have added the url into remote setting

```
   $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx/qualification',
             headers: {"Accept" : "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json" },
             data: JSON.stringify(address),
             crossDomain : true,
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (responseData) {
                console.log(responseData);
            getAddresses();

            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
                var result = $("#selections").append("Sorry, Something in the system has gone wrong , Please try again Later");
                console.log("Sorry, Something in the system has gone wrong , Please try again Later");
            }

        });
```

Comment: can you post the error message you getting.

Comment: Mostly likely failing preflight??

Comment: Remote Site Settings is used for Apex callout. Not applicable for Ajax calls.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal "Sorry, Something in the system has gone wrong , Please try again Later"